# nmcli Error: Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking

Tags: ubuntu, cron, nmcli

I wrote a combination .sh and .exp scripts that:

1. activate vpn connection
2. connect to remote server
3. download some files from server
4. deactivate vpn connection

This scripts should run on schedule.
I use `nmcli` for activate and deactivate connections.
If I run scripts manually it work correctly, but if I run this scripts via `cron`, I receive message (about vpn conn activation): `Error: Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking.`

In logs I see that the script is run from under me:

```
Dec  6 18:48:01 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 CRON[10975]: (maskalev) CMD (./dev/promomed/__DRAFTS__/utils/sftp_monitor/main.sh)
```

my groups:

```
maskalev@maskalev-Aspire-A514-54:~$ groups
maskalev root adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev netdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker
```

nmcli permissions

```
maskalev@maskalev-Aspire-A514-54:~$ nmcli general permissions
PERMISSION                                                        VALUE 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check  yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network             yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics          yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi                yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax               yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan                yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control                    yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload                             auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns         auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname           auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own                yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system             yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake                         no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan                          yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open                    yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected               yes
```

I think I'm interested enable-disable-network, amn't?

Have you any ideas?

May be I can solve this problem (mainly activate vpn) by other way?

OS -- Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39203457/495319 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/681708/comments/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@woodin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4196/wodin) for advice (after 8 months I returned to this question)!

What I did.
Firstly I compared outputs of `nmcli general permissions` launched from terminal and from cron.

From terminal (permissions for me)

```
PERMISSION                                                        VALUE 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check  yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network             yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics          yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi                yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax               yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan                yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control                    yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload                             auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns         auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname           auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own                yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system             yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake                         no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan                          yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open                    yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected               yes
```

From cron (permissions for cron or rather for adm group users)

```
PERMISSION                                                        VALUE 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check  no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network             no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics          no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi                no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax               no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan                no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control                    auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload                             auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns         auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname           auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system             no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake                         no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan                          auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open                    no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected               no
```

All I need in my case is give permission to network-control.
I added `x.pkla` file to `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/` ([Docs here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pklocalauthority.8.html)):

```
[Let adm group modify system settings for network]
Identity=unix-group:adm
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
ResultAny=yes
```

May be you need to reload `polkit` after it.

Check the output:

```
PERMISSION                                                        VALUE 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check  no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network             no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics          no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi                no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax               no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan                no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control                    yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload                             auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns         auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname           auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system             no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake                         no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan                          auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open                    no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected               no
```

Now I can activate (and deactivate) networks via cron!